# Can find an element in Element explorer but cannot find it when running tests

Tags: protractor

Well, I can find an element in element explorer and can play around it but when I put it under my tests and run it, it never finds it. I have tried all waiting for longer time or scrolling to the bottom but nothing helps.

Could this be a case even?

This is how am getting my element - element.all(by.css('[game-provider="NETENT"]')).get(0)

Is there more I have to do in code?
I need to click this element. Any help would be good.

HTML CODE

```
 <head></head>
    <body class="base not-mobile ng-scope" data-ng-controller="BaseCtrl">
        <div class="base-view app-loaded" data-ng-class="cssClass.appState">
            <!-- uiView:-->
            <div class="ng-scope" data-ui-view="">
                <!--   uiView: undefined    -->
                <ui-view class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="startPage ng-scope" data-ng-controller="StartPageCtrl">
                        <gfp-tabs class="ng-isolate-scope" pam-fixed=""></gfp-tabs>
                        <gfp-application-bar class="ng-isolate-scope"></gfp-application-bar>   <gfp-overlay class="ng-isolate-scope"></gfp-overlay> <gfp-content-loader class="ng-isolate-scope" url="http://private-21c39-mrgcms.apiary-mock.com/en-se/pages/start"></gfp-content-loader>   <gfp-game-list class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <ul class="pure-g">
        <!--ngRepeat: game in ::ctrl.games   -->
        <gfp-game-item class="pure-u-1-2 ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" vineet="jain" game-provider="NETENT" game="{"gameId":"south_park_desktop_netent","name":"South Park","w…":false,"friendlyName":"south-park","gameProvider":"NETENT"}" ng-repeat="game in ::ctrl.games"></gfp-game-item>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: game in ::ctrl.games -->
        <gfp-game-item class="pure-u-1-2 ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" vineet="jain" game-provider="NETENT" game="{"gameId":"aliens_desktop_netent","name":"Aliens","width":64…lete":false,"friendlyName":"aliens","gameProvider":"NETENT"}" ng-repeat="game in ::ctrl.games"></gfp-game-item>
        <!--end ngRepeat: game in ::ctrl.games  -->
        <gfp-game-item class="pure-u-1-2 ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" vineet="jain" game-provider="MICRO" game="{"gameId":"mermaids_millions_desktop_microgaming","name":"Me…e,"friendlyName":"mermaids-millions","gameProvider":"MICRO"}" ng-repeat="game in ::ctrl.games"></gfp-game-item>
        <!--end ngRepeat: game in ::ctrl.games  -->
        <gfp-game-item class="pure-u-1-2 ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" vineet="jain" game-provider="OGS" game="{"gameId":"easy_slider_desktop_ogs","name":"Easy Slider Ifra…te":false,"friendlyName":"easy_slider","gameProvider":"OGS"}" ng-repeat="game in ::ctrl.games"></gfp-game-item>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: game in ::ctrl.games -->
    </ul>
```

Comment: could you provide some HTML code?

Comment: I have edited the question now and added the HTML code

Comment: looks like it should grab it. Could you provide some script code which you use. Maybe element is not loaded yet when you navigate to this page or smth like that.

Comment: I put browser.sleep to 30000 just for same purpose but still not successful, also it finds very quickly in element explorer. this is bugging me out.

Comment: @hny2015 what about `li[game-provider=NETENT]` css selector?

Comment: @alecxe -- I tried this but again it only works in Element Explorer and not when I run tests                                                                                     element.all(by.css('li[game-provider="NETENT"]')).first().click()              Could it be a case that is not under ng-repeater, because when I try to click first on ng-repeater that works but I want to play first from NETENT.

Comment: I'd recommend running in debug mode.  Add a `browser.debugger();` statement immediately before you run the assertion in your code. And then launch protractor with the `debug` option. Press 'c' to continue the first time and then you will get to your assertion. Look in the browser's console for the element you want.

Comment: I think you are right, I tried through debugger, and I cant find it there but also it doesnt have any FindByCSS and only findBYCSSselector which is not finding what I want, though it finds perfectly for ng-repeater but that is not what I want.... Also, how come it finds every single time in element explorer? Someone got to help me, this is psyching me out. I may be completely stupid for missing small piece but please see and help if anyone can.

Comment: this is the latest I tried - element.all(by.css('gfp-game-item[game-provider="NETENT"]')).first()